# How to hide PWM.add_channel_pulse(dma_channel, gpio, start, width) output?

Tags: python, pwm

I use `RPIO.PWM` to control servos. All the time, the `PWM.add_channel_pulse(dma_channel, gpio, start, width)` method is called, text about the change is displayed *(see image)*. I know there is a way *(&> /dev/null)* to hide all the output, but I don't want to hide the entire Python script's output, only the output displayed by the `PWM.add_channel_pulse(dma_channel, gpio, start, width)`.

[image: Output that sould be hidden]

Comment: Do you remember where you downloaded RPIO.GPIO from?  It's odd that just one debug statement is being printed.

Comment: I've chosen the easiest way from there: http://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/#installation
EDIT: not only one debug statement is being printed, but the others are printed just once

Comment: Ah, that's fine, I was wondering if you had picked up a modified source.  Removing the line I mentioned in the answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to edit the source to remove the line and then rebuild.

The line is in the file source/c_pwm/pwm.c in the source directory.

Remove line 458 of pwm.c

> log_debug("add_channel_pulse: channel=%d, gpio=%d, start=%d, width=%d\n", channel, gpio, width_start, width);

There are other log_debug lines in the code.  It's odd that just the one appears to come to the screen.

Comment: I've dowloaded the zipped file from [there](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/archive/master.tar.gz), and uncommented the line, but I'm not able to recompile it. How to do it? (on RPI or Win7)

Comment: @Alex Just do what you did during the original install of RPIO (apart from downloading the zip again).  The build method you used should recompile the C program as part of the install.